# Clarifications on the use of comments

Tags: discussion, faq, moderation, comments, etiquette

There is fairly comprehensive general guidance on using comments in the official [Stack Exchange Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and [the Help Center topic on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).  There is also extensive discussion of specific comment-related topics you can find in searches of Meta Stack Exchange.

So this isn't intended to replicate or summarize comprehensive guidance.  Rather, this is intended as a reference page for various specific comment-related questions that may be commonly misunderstood and arise on this site.  It will add some context and explanation that is often lacking in the general guidance.

Component questions are identified and answered as individual answers, with links to them in this question as an index (FAQ-style).  This thread can be expanded as new questions arise.

[**Are expressions of appreciation appropriate comments?**](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/577/8251)

[**Should comments be used for discussion or debate?**](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/578/8251)

[**Is social conversation or something similar unrelated to the post appropriate in comments?**](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/579/8251)

[**Is it appropriate to use comments to criticize or scold a user?**](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/580/8251)

[**Comments and Links**](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/581/8251)

Answer (score 1):

### Are expressions of appreciation appropriate comments?

Most of the discussion of this in places like the Help Center and Meta SE is about "thanks" comments, and correctly identifies them as noise.  However, it's a little more nuanced than that.

If the comment is limited to "thanks" or something equivalent, it is basically noise, but not entirely noise.  It should be deleted, but doesn't need to be deleted immediately.

People invest their time writing answers to help others, and get satisfaction from feedback that their effort was helpful and appreciated. Voting is the proper way to provide this feedback, but questioners, especially new users, often don't do that, or lack the rep to do it. Even if they do vote, the thanks are supplemental feedback that is rewarding. It doesn't hurt anything to leave it in place temporarily until the answerer has had a chance to see it.

If the comment includes wording that the answer was helpful or solved the problem, it also serves another purpose. Again, the correct way to express that is by upvoting and/or accepting the answer, and acceptance can be suggested in a comment if the questioner indicates it solved their problem<sup>[1]</sup>. If the answer is accepted, or heavily upvoted by other users, the comments about helpfulness and acceptance become superfluous.

But in other cases, it may be the only indication that the answer was helpful. Other readers may be hesitant to vote on the answer if it looks good but they aren't sure whether it is actually helpful. A comment from the questioner can address that and lead to voting by the community. In the absence of acceptance or multiple upvotes, these kinds of comments are often the only indication of the value of an answer, in which case they serve a useful purpose as a stand-in.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Note that this is better suggested by someone other than the answerer. Otherwise be careful navigating the line between educating new users and "rep-chasing". See for example, [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer).*

Answer (score 1):

### Should comments be used for discussion or debate?

By design, Stack Exchange sites use a Q&A format that is not intended to support interactive discussion within the questions and answers that compose the knowledge base. But some discussion or debate in comments can be important to elicit author clarification or fine-tune the post, or to add subject matter context or clarification.

This is an intended use of comments.  For example, [the Help Center topic on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) recommends using comments to:

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Add relevant but minor ... information to a post ...

Nothing precludes multiple users from doing that. The recommendations on when **not** to use comments includes:

> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

Comments don't start out as discussions or debates, they turn into discussions or debates. It is when they turn into a discussion or debate that a decision should be made about the appropriateness of moving it elsewhere.

Discussion that gets reflected in the post becomes superfluous as comments. On the other hand, a brief, constructive interchange about the subject matter can provide clarification on an issue. It might be too much of a digression from the intended point of the post to include it within the post, but it could be appropriate to leave in place as information for other readers.

The issue isn't really whether **any** discussion or debate (concerning a question's topics) is appropriate in comments, the issue is with **lengthy** discussion or debate; the comment area is not intended for that. A long comment thread also distracts from other posts and makes the actual posts harder to read.

The appropriate venue for lengthy discussion<sup>[1]</sup> or debate is chat for subject matter discussions, or A&C Meta for policy or behavior discussions. Participants can move a discussion to a chat room if it gets long or is expected to get long, or excessively long comment threads can be culled or moved to chat by a moderator.

But be aware that chat rooms need to meet certain requirements to avoid eventual automated deletion. There must be at least 15 messages from at least two users for the room to be permanent (in which case it can become frozen and archived due to inactivity but will still be reachable via the link and can be unfrozen if necessary for additional posting).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Note that a "lengthy discussion" isn't necessarily limited to side issues; it could include supplemental details directly related to the post. For example, a lengthy tutorial on how to accomplish something mentioned in the post that is chopped up into a long series of comments.*

Answer (score 1):

### Is social conversation or something similar unrelated to the post appropriate in comments?

It is not an intended use of comments, but exceptions are often made, and the acceptance of it varies widely by site. The issue was discussed in the Meta.SE thread [Is it cool to have "fun" comment-discussions unrelated to an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322091/is-it-cool-to-have-fun-comment-discussions-unrelated-to-an-answer)

For example, a humorous comment that is entertaining to the entire community might be left in place. A personal conversation of a social nature between two users (often referred to as "chit chat"), is pretty universally considered noise that distracts from the post and is inappropriate on a post. The place for that would be the site's general chat room or another chat room.

Keep in mind that most of the readers of any Q&A post are people who find the post through a search. **Question** and **answer** posts should ideally resemble Wikipedia articles — containing only information written for a general audience, not a conversation with the questioner or other user.

There is a little more leeway in comments because they are naturally more like interactions between users and not considered "content".  Nevertheless, they are attached to the post and can be read by everyone who lands there.

It is preferred for comments to be as succinct as possible, but a minor amount of social nicety within a comment that is otherwise informational is completely acceptable. Just be cognizant of the effect the comments will have on the random strangers who search for useful information, and that it is part of what they will find and need to wade through.

Answer (score 1):

### Is it appropriate to use comments to criticize or scold a user?

Stack Exchange sites are based on community moderation. In addition to curating content, the community members perform an important role in helping new users learn the ropes of posting and participating.  This is done largely through comments.  For example, [the Help Center topic on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) includes these examples of when you should comment:

- Request clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;

Some other examples would relate to things such as explaining posting etiquette (e.g., accepting an answer that the question author says solved the problem, or not invalidating answers by modifying the question), or violations of participation and posting rules (e.g., cross-site posting or excessive self-promotion).

Since these comments are needed mainly as corrective action when someone gets something wrong, it is almost all negative feedback (although it should be written in a polite, constructive way).

You can read some historical discussion about this in the Meta.SE thread [Is it appropriate to directly ask users to alter their behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132762/is-it-appropriate-to-directly-ask-users-to-alter-their-behavior).

**Negative feedback**

By definition, these comments will be criticism. Properly written comments of this type will be polite criticism of the user's content or action, but should not be criticism of the user personally. Still, to a new user who isn't familiar with posting on a curated site, even that may seem like personal criticism.

Writing styles vary; some people write in a succinct or brusk style that could be perceived as scolding when it involves negative feedback. But actual scolding language is typically a reaction to dealing with a problem caused by a user who should know better (you rarely see new users being scolded for mistakes). The typical situation is an experienced user causing grief for others by making a "new user" mistake, or a user who repeatedly engages in problematic actions despite the problem having been explained to them.

Scolding another user in comments is not the preferred way to provide feedback, but it doesn't violate any rules unless it is unconstructive or contains language that violates the Code of Conduct.

**Who can post negative feedback in comments?**

Any user with comment privileges can use comments for community moderation. In situations where other users are being adversely affected by an action, such comments can easily lead to conflict, or escalate and end up with the commenter doing something regretable. So it is generally preferable to just flag these problems for moderator attention and let the moderators deal with it.

**I thought negative feedback is done in private.**

Virtually all community moderation that does not involve editing posts is done in public via comments.

Moderators also handle issues involving violations of site participation rules or actions that disrupt the site:

- A problem serious enough to warrant an official warning or disciplinary action (serious scolding), is never handled in comments. There is a mechanism in place for moderators to do that in private. The nature of the problem might have been discussed in comments independent of the remedial action, but any "scolding" interaction with the user is handled in private.
- Actions that don't rise to the level for which official action is warranted are handled in public, using comments, where other users can potentially benefit from it. So getting negative feedback in comments is probably the preferred way to get it.

**How should negative feedback comments be written?**

Negative feedback comments should be polite and focus on the content, action or behavior, rather than the person. The Help Center guidance recommends **not posting**:

> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("*-1, see previous comments you scallywag!*"); instead, downvote (and provide or upvote a better answer if appropriate);

- For example, a question author changes the question in a way that invalidates posted answers: a comment pointing out the problem is appropriate, but a comment calling the question author a derogatory term for having done it would not be appropriate.
- As another example, someone repeatedly does something problematic that has been explained to them. In this case, stick to the facts of what is the problem and the repetition of it; avoid suggesting ulterior motives or character flaws behind the action, or labeling the user based on the behavior.
- Ideally, the comment should explain the problem or ramifications of the action, and/or link to guidelines in Help or relevant Meta discussions, since this is intended as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

### Comments and Links

1. **Are there direct links for individual comments?**

   Each comment does have its own link, which is displayed if you hover on the comment's timestamp. Right-clicking the timestamp accesses the context menu options, which include copying the URL. The full range of context menu options for the URL will depend on your browser and operating system.

   There's further (historical) information at [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment).

---

2. **Is there a way to shorten Stack Exchange links in comments?**

   Because Stack Exchange URLs tend to be quite long, you might run out of precious comment space. Instead of having to add another comment, you can use the [shortened form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164194/) of the URL:

   `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164194/`

   Compare that URL with the default format:

   `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164194/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-stack-overflow-urls`

   Note that direct links for comments are different from question and answer URLs. The comment URL that is linked to its date stamp is a supported feature. If you know the comment's index number, there is a shortened form you can use it in, and there are other shortened URL forms for comments. These are described in the discussion cited above on direct comment links. However, according to that discussion, some shortened URL forms for comments may not always be reliable.